# At which point can Magento SE get its own URL?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if at some point, we can get an url like http://superuser.com and get rid of the .stackexchange.com ?

We better use http://magename.me/ for the naming

Comment: I don't think that will ever happen. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124327/whats-the-eligibility-criteria-for-a-se-site-to-get-dedicated-domain-name#comment332729_124327

Comment: @Marius thanks for that, even if I didn't want to hear that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I currently own Mageoverflow.com and have been hoping at some point I could transfer it over to host this site there. But it has been addressed before and I don't think that it is going to happen. This was covered here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

Comment: Well at least you gave yourself a change by buying the domain name ^^ did you get the MageOverflow name via your magename.me ? :p

Comment: haha no - it was called mageoverflow by Tim B for a few years I think